# Looping thru specified sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through specified worksheets in a workbook and assign labels etc. I get the message "Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range. Here is the code that I am using...

```
Sub Labels()

Dim intStartRow As Integer
Dim intRowCount As Integer
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim WshtNames As Variant
Dim intSheet As Variant

intStartRow = 32

WshtNames = Array("shtAngola", "shtBotswana", "shtMozambique", "shtNamibia", "shtSA", "shtZambia", "shtZimbabwe", "shtEritrea", "shtEthiopia", "shtKenya", "shtRwanda", "shtTanzania", "shtUganda", "shtAlgeria", "shtEgypt", "shtMorocco", "shtTunisia", "shtGhana", "shtIvoryCoast", "shtMauritius", "shtNigeria", "shtSenegal")

For Each intSheet In WshtNames

   With Worksheets(intSheet)

      For intRowCount = 7 To 21
           For intRow = 1 To 3
               .Cells(intStartRow, 1) = shtSelections.Cells(intRowCount, 1)
```

Would be very grateful for your help.

Best,
Adam

Comment: My guess would be a spelling issue, seems most likely judging by the huge sheetname array youve made. Double check the spelling of those. Out of range errors for me usually means I've spelled something wrong or I'm trying to iterate over col or row number 0 which dont exist.

Comment: Also you should probably show where in your code 'shtSelections' is defined.

Comment: Agree with @WouldBeNerd, but Err 9 will also be thrown if these sheets are on a different workbook than your active one, so make sure the parent of `Worksheets` is set too.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps will you associate a row with marking flag. So you use the second auto var in loop. *intRowCount* instad of *intStartRow*.

.Cells(intRowCount, 1) = shtSelections.Cells(intRowCount, 1)